# Is there a reason for compiling an indirect jump as two instructions instead of one on ARM?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, clang, compiler-optimization

Given the following tiny program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NEXT goto **ip++
#define guard(n) asm("#" #n)

int main() {
  static void  *prog[] = {&&next1,&&next2,&&next1,&&next3,&&next1,&&next4,&&next1,&&next5,&&next1,&&loop};
  void ** ip=prog;
  int    count = 100000000;
  NEXT;

 next1: guard(1); NEXT;
 next2: guard(2); NEXT;
 next3: guard(3); NEXT;
 next4: guard(4); NEXT;
 next5: guard(5); NEXT;
 loop:
  if (count) {
    count--;
    ip=prog;
    NEXT;
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

I noticed that each of the next# statements get compiled as TWO instructions.

```
        ldr     r2, [r3], #4
        mov     pc, r2    @ indirect register jump
```

I would have expected this to only need one instruction:

```
        ldr pc, [r3], #4
```

I found the discussion here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40887

"The problem is that the instruction "ldr pc, [r3, #0]" is not considered a function call by the Cortex-A8's branch predictor, as noted in DDI0344J section 5.2.1, Return stack predictions. Thus, the return from the called function is mispredicted resulting in a penalty of 13 cycles compared to a direct call."

However, the 'goto' is not a function call and there's no expectation for the return stack to be relevant here at all.

I'm wondering if this is some optimization that both GCC and CLANG have missed or is the latter a worse performer for a reason I'm un aware of?

Comment: Yes, bug #40887 is only about indirect calls with `blx` vs. manually setting up a return address and jumping.  It's not relevant to indirect jumps inside a function, like for a `switch` or computed goto.  (Except perhaps if GCC is avoiding loads into PC in general, so this missed optimization is collateral damage from fixing that bug.)  And you're not using `volatile`, another thing that often makes GCC do a load with a separate instruction instead of folding it into something else (like avoiding x86 `add eax, [rdi]`.)

Comment: did you compile for debug?  what were your command line options?  what version of the compiler?

Comment: @old_timer every version, every optimization level and both gcc and clang do the exact same thing. Interestingly, if you compile -Og or -Os then you get EVEN WORSE code -- a branch to a branch. https://godbolt.org/z/98f6edjse

Comment: There are restrictions on use of some addressing modes and the PC, but that would be the place of `r3` as a source, and not a destination.  I wonder is some restriction is over zealous in restricting this.  However, this is a little weird for the compiler as normally it is operating on basic blocks and you are forming a dispatch table structure.  I think this is probably the reason.

Comment: The assembler and machine architecture does not prohibit it.  There is also possible restrictions due to relocations.

Comment: This is allowed in ARM (not Thumb) and is considered one of the most basic of peephole optimizations. Someone on the GCC dev team should maybe be notified since this pattern is heavily used in emulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This looks like a missed optimization** unless there is some *other* microarchitectural reason to avoid it on some other CPUs.  (That's plausible, but I wouldn't specifically expect it.  Loading into a register multiple instructions earlier could give some time to hide load-use latency and reduce possible mispredict penalty, but loading in the previous instruction is unlikely to matter unless there's something special about ldr into PC.)

You're correct, bug #40887 is only about indirect calls with `blx` vs. manually setting up a return address and jumping.  It's not relevant to indirect jumps inside a function, like for a `switch` or computed goto.  (Except perhaps if GCC is avoiding loads into PC in general, so this missed optimization is collateral damage from fixing that bug.)

And you're not using `volatile`, another thing that often makes GCC do a load with a separate instruction instead of folding it into something else (like avoiding x86 `add eax, [rdi]`.  Or in this case a memory-source jump like ARM load-into-PC, it might consider that special.)

---

Comparing `-mcpu=cortex-a8` `-marm` vs. `-mthumb`, we see GCC does need extra instructions in thumb mode to set the low bit of the target address before `mov pc,reg`.  https://godbolt.org/z/87EszvWP1

Or maybe that's a missed optimization, too: just `ldr pc, [mem]` would stay in the current mode, and we know we're jumping within a single function so there's no possibility of *changing* mode.  And/or the jump table could just have been built with the low bits already set if using `bx r2` is actually faster.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/ldr--register-offset- says

> For word loads, Rt can be the PC. A load to the PC causes a branch to the address loaded. In ARMv4, bits[1:0] of the address loaded must be 0b00. In ARMv5T and above, bits[1:0] must not be 0b10, and if bit[0] is 1, execution continues in Thumb state, otherwise execution continues in ARM state.

In Thumb mode, `ldr` into PC is only possible with a 32-bit instruction, but ldr into r0-7 and branching to it can each be 16-bit instructions.  But I doubt that would be any better unless you can schedule the load earlier.

Comment: Indeed, that's two missed optimizations; it should know the labels are part of a thumb function and should already have the low bit set. Though branching to labels outside of the current function could make this particular optimization rather tricky.

Comment: ARM CLANG does *NOT* add the ORR operation, so it's able to do this properly. It still has the other issue, however.

Comment: @ReneeCousins: GNU C labels-as-values only supports goto within the current function.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html  Since a non-local goto would be UB, GCC and clang are allowed to assume it doesn't happen.